# JavaScript Compatibility View Issue

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

I have a function that I have coded to throw an error message when a particular select doesn't have a value. The problem that I am having is that I have environment (when running from Netbeans) that sees this html value fine and works but when it is on the server it does not see the html and gives a value of "" and doesn't work correctly. Any help appreciated cause I'm stumped.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function CheckForm(obj, optMsgDiv) {
   if(obj != "") {
    return true;
   } else {
      if(optMsgDiv != "") {
        var messageObj = document.getElementById(optMsgDiv);
        var clearObj = document.getElementById('refUpdMethod').value;

        alert("value: " + clearObj + "  Obj: " + obj);

        if(clearObj != "") {
           //goes to this part of the code on my local
            return true;
        } else {
           //goes this part of the code hosted on the server 
            var message = getErrorMsg();
            DisplayErrorMessage(clearObj, messageObj, message);
        }
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<macsweb:button label="<< Close >>" updModeAction="if(CheckForm '${refUpdMethod}','messages_container${counter}${refUpdate.CASE_REFERENCE_UPDATE_SEQ_NBR}') == false)return false;if(recordList.checkList()==false)return false;else{recordList.clearList('${parentDiv}'); temp = validateBeforeSubmit('${closeUrl}?action=c','${divID}','${closeMessage}','','','true','',document.forms['frmRefUpdateBilling${counter}${refUpdate.CASE_REFERENCE_UPDATE_SEQ_NBR}'],'Y','','messages_container${counter}${refUpdate.CASE_REFERENCE_UPDATE_SEQ_NBR}');
                                if(temp)disableSingleField(this);}"
                                style="font-weight: bold; display:${(sessionScope.aBean.updatesCloseStatus > 1) ? '' : 'none'}"
                                />

<td align="right">Method Used &nbsp;</td>
        <td>   
            <select id="refUpdMethod" name="refUpdMethod" >
                <c:forEach items="${refUpdateBean.validMethods}" var="eaMethod">
                    <option value="${eaMethod}" ${(refUpdate.REFERENCE_UPDATE_METHOD eq eaMethod) ? 'selected' : ' '} >${eaMethod}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <macsweb:dumpOriginalValues fieldName="refUpdMethod" fieldValue="${refUpdate.REFERENCE_UPDATE_METHOD}" />
        </td>
```

Comment: where is the html for the element you are trying to get, with ID `refUpdMethod` ?

Comment: Your question is tagged as JavaScript and HTML but you're obviously using some (server-side?) preprocessor you haven't mentioned. Can you please re-tag the question?

Comment: So I found out what my problem was it was that it works one with Compatibility View in IE on and with it off.